# What is a single word for "No longer employed at this company"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I was thinking of "terminated" but that implies the person may have been fired. I've also heard "resigned", but that's a little specific (some people may have voluntarily resigned, others may have been fired).

Can anyone think of a neutral, single word?

Comment: In what context?

Comment: We have a list of employees we're sending to our home office.

Comment: People who used to work for the company but left are said to be *off-roll*, i.e., no longer on the payroll.

Comment: How about "former"?

Comment: Your requirement is still not clear. If you are sending a list of employees somewhere, you would simply *not* include the _ex-employees_! You should include an example sentence, else (a) `your question may be closed by strict moderators` and (b) `your question may not attract good responses because answers on such question are also sometimes penalized!`

Comment: @deadrat You've used the most general word in passing. "Left" covers all situations except dying in post. The only term that's more general is "no longer with us" which is not a single word.

Comment: *Separated* is sometimes used, but it also carries a negative connotation.

Comment: _Departed_ might work for an internal document, especially if you pair it with the company name: "Departed Three Initial Corporation" or "Departed TIC" makes clear that the person no longer works at the company (for unspecified reasons) without suggesting that he or she has shuffled off this mortal coil altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**unaffiliated** - not officially attached to or connected with an organization or group.

Comment: Could you give some further explanation?

Answer (score 2):

The mundane term is *nonstaff*, derived from [*staff*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/staff).

> **Staff** *noun*
> [treated as singular or plural] All the people employed by a particular organization
> [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/staff)
>
> **Non-staff** *adjective*
> Not staff (regular employees).
> [- yourdictionary.com](http://www.yourdictionary.com/nonstaff) (Also at [wikitionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nonstaff))

Comment: Hmm. Personally I'd expect to see "non-staff" used in a situation to include people who work in an office, but not employed directly by that company. An example phrase would be "We have 78 people in our office on a normal day: 76 employees of XYZ Inc. and two non-staff (namely Sid and Gytha, the cleaners)". I wouldn't expect to see the phrase to mean *former* employees.

Comment: @AndyT, that's what I was thinking. Non-staff isn't a bad answer but it seems like it would apply to volunteers.

Comment: @AndyT The question I answered was the original: "*What is a single word for "Not employed at this company"?*" Although the [original question body](http://english.stackexchange.com/revisions/360668/1) spoke in terms of employment, it wasn't restrictive. My answer includes a wide range of people "not employed at this company", such as visitors, inspectors, customers, etc.

Comment: @Tensigh alwayslearning changed your question after I posted my answer, making it (my answer) less relevant. Please see my comment above. Was that change in line with the intent of your original question?

Comment: @Lawrence, yes, the edit is correct. I meant to say "no longer working at this company". Your answer would be more appropriate for the original question (for the record, I gave you a point up).

Answer (score 1):

As you want to refer to *ex-employees* you could say they have *left*, *gone*, or *moved on*. You do need to be a little careful in your context - you don't want to imply they've died.